# Centre a <?php include_once()?>

Tags: html, center

I am learning php and web design and I'm working on my first site. Things are mostly going well however I've hit a bit of a wall I'm wondering if one of you might be able to help me out with.

I am using a header template php as my header on all pages of a site (header_template.php). When I try and include this header template in my homepage (index.php) I am inserting the include_once tag into the header .html tag like:

```
<header>
<?php include_once(header_template.php)?>
</header>
```

This is working fine except I can't get the header centred on the page. In header_template.php, the header it self is centred. I've tried wrapping the header in a div align = "centre" tag but that's not working for me.

Any tips?

Comment: You problem is a simple html problem and has nothing to do at all with php. Show the HTML code produced.

Comment: Hahaha, thank you for making me laugh. use `style="margin:0 auto;"`, or define `margin:0 auto;` for your wrapping div.

Comment: `align` should be `center`, not `centre`. As others have mentioned, use `margin:0 auto;` to center an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use css's auto value for margin?

```
<div style="margin:auto">Centered stuff</div>
```

Comment: Haha, I'm glad my question was amusing...I can accept that. I know it would be incredibly basic for you guys but I was hoping you'd still be able to help out - which you have. 

Thank you for your helpful answers. Just so I'm clear. Would the code which centers the whole header look like this?
 
<div style="margin:auto">
<header>
<?php include_once(header_template.php)?>
</header>
</div>

Comment: Geoffroy, I'm still having trouble getting the header centered. 

In index.php

<body>

<div id="pageheader">
<?php include_once ("template_header.php"); ?>
</div>

In style.css

#pageheader { width: 1024px; margin:0 auto;; border: 1px solid #ff0000; text-align:right }

In template_header.php

<div id="pageHeader" align="center"><table width="1024 px" border="0">
  <tr>
    
    <td width="43%" align="left"><a href="index.php"><img src="style/Logo.png" width="250" height="167" alt="Logo" /></a></td>
      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      </td>
   
    
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.